# duda con Cursor type_warning

Tags: sql, cursor

No logro entender como funciona este tipo de cursor alguien sabe o tiene algún ejemplo en SQL?? 
En la documentación dice esto:

> Especifica que se envía un mensaje de advertencia al cliente cuando el cursor se convierte implícitamente del tipo solicitado a otro.

no se a que se refiere con que se convierte implícitamente en otro tipo, en que casos ocurre eso??

saludos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Una conversión implícita se produce cuando el tipo declarado y el tipo del valor no coinciden y no se indica una conversión de forma explícita. Como por ejemplo:

```
string variable = 2;
```

Dependiendo del lenguaje este tipo de conversiones no están permitidas, fallan o algunas conversiones si se producen y otras no. Con los cursores pasa algo parecido. Ya que tienen un tipo declarado, y la consulta sobre la que usamos el cursor es el "*valor*" del cursor y tiene un tipo concreto.

Los cursores tienen un tipo definido cuando se declaran. Si se establece el `TYPE_WARNING` manda un aviso cuando el tipo declarado y el tipo "*real*" del cursor no coinciden.

Por ejemplo, si el cursor se declara como `KEYSET` pero la consulta que se le pasa contiene una tabla sin un índice único, el cursor se comportará como `STATIC`.

Hay una [tabla con las conversiones implícitas en la documentación](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/ms190641.aspx) que ilustra que conversiones implícitas hay y cual será el comportamiento dependiendo de la discordancia de tipos.